# SQLite and Android Insert/Updates on SQLiteDatabase -CompiledStatements-

Tags: android, sqlite, insert, compilation

Pretend I have a table with 2 columns.  _id and name.  _id is the primary key and I do not want to set this value manually. I want to perform an insert of name="john," and let the program create my own _id.  I am unclear what "index" to use when inserting and how many question marks to use.  Does this code do the job?  Should the index for john be 1 or 2?

```
String TABLENAME = "table";

SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO "+TABLENAME+" VALUES(?);");    

statement.bindString(1,"john");

statement.executeInsert();
```

Next, say I want to manually set my own _id value.  Would I change the code to:

```
String TABLENAME = "table";

SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO "+TABLENAME+" VALUES(?,?);");  

statement.bindLong(1,666);  //Manual _id.

statement.bindString(2,"john");

statement.executeInsert();
```

Comment: @Sandy: no, the first example shouldn't and doesn't work. sqlite will not "guess" that the value provided is to be put in the second column.

Comment: @sixfeetsix In the SQLite documentation, it says that if a null value is passed as a primary key, then SQLite will automatically create a key.  So, with one question mark, I would assume that it would interpret that I am passing null for the key, and then "john" for the, technically, 2nd param (column "name").  Regardless, I think I mind find it easier to manually address all columns, then for the first column pass null.  This would auto-create the primary key and let me pass whatever other values, and in the future allow me to manually use my own keys.

Comment: @user817129: please see my update for an example of how to pass, or not, a value for the autoincrement column.

Comment: I got it figured out.  I'll use the column names and pass the values accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first example where you provide only the name will not work:

```
sqlite> create table test (i integer primary key autoincrement, j text);
sqlite> insert into test values ('asd');
Error: table test has 2 columns but 1 values were supplied
sqlite> insert into test values (null, 'asd');
sqlite> select * from test;
1|asd
sqlite> insert into test (j) values ('asd');
sqlite> select * from test;
1|asd
2|asd
```

so you need to identify the name column as the destination of the sole value this way, (or as you mentioned in your comment pass null):

```
SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO "+TABLENAME+" (name) VALUES(?);");
```

Your second example should work fine.

This would apply to some table created this way:

```
create table SomeTable (_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text)
```

Answer (score 3):

Then

```
    SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO "+TABLENAME+" VALUES(null,?);");
    statement.bindString(1,"john");
```

Should also work.